# cannot create luminus project with sqlite and clojurescript support

Tags: sqlite, clojure, clojurescript, luminus

I am trying to create a luminus project with sqlite and cljs support with this command:

```
lein new dbscript +sqlite +cljs
```

but I keep getting this error message all the time:

```
Failed to resolve version for dbscript:lein-template:jar:RELEASE: Could not find metadata dbscript:lein-template/maven-metadata.xml in local (/home/jonas/.m2/repository)
Failed to read artifact descriptor for dbscript:lein-template:jar:RELEASE
This could be due to a typo in :dependencies, file system permissions, or network issues.
If you are behind a proxy, try setting the 'http_proxy' environment variable.
Could not find template dbscript on the classpath.
```

and I cannot find any solution to this. Any suggestions?

Comment: probably it should be `lein new luminus dbscript +sqlite +cljs`

Comment: ok, that solved the problem. thanks. now I have to run figwheel and then run lein run to get a rather plain webpage, with no css, just a plain text saying welcome to dbscript. is that the way it should be with cljs support?

Comment: @JonasFredriksson uh yes? What were you expecting?

Comment: something similar to the page you get when creating a luminus project without cljs support, full css support, etc.